# Unix epoch time to Java Date object

Tags: java, date, java-time

I have a string containing the [UNIX Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and I need to convert it to a Java Date object.

```
String date = "1081157732";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(""); // This line
try {
  Date expiry = df.parse(date);
 } catch (ParseException ex) {
  ex.getStackTrace();
}
```

The marked line is where I'm having trouble. I can't work out what the argument to SimpleDateFormat() should be, or even if I should be using SimpleDateFormat().

Comment: See [my detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20370992/642706) to a similar question on converting between milliseconds to date-time with example code using Joda-Time library.

Comment: `private String getDateString(long timeInMilliseconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        return formatter.format(timeInMilliseconds);
    } `

Answer (score 150, accepted):

How about just:

```
Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
```

EDIT: as per [rde6173](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62195/rde6173)'s answer and taking a closer look at the input specified in the question , "1081157732" appears to be a seconds-based epoch value so you'd want to multiply the long from parseLong() by 1000 to convert to milliseconds, which is what Java's Date constructor uses, so:

```
Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong(date) * 1000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this technically be incorrect as it doesn't take into account leap seconds?

Comment: Maciej, op's "seconds-based" epoch already accounts for leap seconds, it is "seconds"-based. So this answer is correct.

Comment: It gives me incorrect values if multiplied by 1000, isn't there a better way of doing it?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The question was since the epoch, which is UTC while date expects the long to be from GMT, are they they same?

Answer (score 47):

Epoch is the number of **seconds** since Jan 1, 1970..

So:

```
String epochString = "1081157732";
long epoch = Long.parseLong( epochString );
Date expiry = new Date( epoch * 1000 );
```

For more information:
http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: This works a treat ...IDK Y this hasn't been checked as Answer :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I was sitting here trying to instantiate a date from an epoch and the result was always some day in 1970, and it was because I was unknowingly giving Java milliseconds, not seconds :)

Answer (score 36):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;

long epoch = Long.parseLong("1081157732");
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epoch);
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC); # ZonedDateTime = 2004-04-05T09:35:32Z[UTC]
```

In this case you should better use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to mark it as date in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone because Epoch is defined in UTC in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) used by Java.

[`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) contains a handy constant for the UTC time zone, as seen in last line above. Its superclass, [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) can be used to adjust into other time zones.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest dropping the `LocalDateTime` and just show a `ZonedDateTime`. In most business apps, `ZonedDateTime` is the best way to go. People tend to get themselves into trouble/confusion with the `LocalXXX` types.

Answer (score 12):

```
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date)
Date expiry = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert seconds time stamp to millisecond time stamp. You could use the TimeUnit API and neat like this.

`long milliSecondTimeStamp = MILLISECONDS.convert(secondsTimeStamp, SECONDS)`

Answer (score -1):

Hum.... if I am not mistaken, the UNIX Epoch time is actually the same thing as

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

So writing

```
try {
    Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // ...
}
```

should work (and be much faster that date parsing)

Comment: Usually Unix epoch time is measured in seconds, not milliseconds.