# UNIX programming

Tags: solaris, unix-timestamp, sunos

Hi i want to convert UNIX date to normal date (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
22222,0,0,0,14387
33333,0,0,0,14170
44444,0,0,0,14244
55555,0,0,0,14190
66666,0,0,0,14528
77777,0,0,0,14200
88888,0,0,0,0
99999,0,0,0,0
```

here 5th column represents UNIX date

i want to convert into

```
22222,0,0,0,2009-05-23
```

and similarly remaining rows

can any body help me

Comment: Language? Context? You're going to have to give us something to go on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix epoch time to Java Date Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object)

Answer (score 5):

A simple awk script ought to do it

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} { print $1,$2,$3,$4,strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$5) }' myFile.txt
```

Cheers.

**EDIT:**
You're not using unix timestamps, but I checked your data, and it appears you're using days since the epoch, so here goes:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} { print $1,$2,$3,$4,strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$5*86400) }' myFile.txt
```

Comment: @roe, That's not correct. Is it even possible to extract the year from an epoch using only a small part?

Comment: @Anders; you're right.. Well, it would've been correct, if it was actually unix timestamps, but they're not.. :P

Comment: @roe, Your output is giving me `22222,0,0,0,1970-01-01`, looking at the op's question, that's a few years apart. Edit: yeah that's what I figured also.

Comment: @roe, I would give you two votes up, since you actually bothered looking into the reason why this was failing.

Comment: 9842631423,0,0,0,nawk: calling undefined function strftime

Comment: @asn123; try replacing `awk` with `gawk` (which is the GNU version of awk) if you have it, it appears you're using a version of awk which doesn't have `strftime`.

Comment: i am using below come
nawk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} {print $0,strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$5*86400)}'

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

any function has to be defined before this command
please help

Comment: @asn123; as I said, try using the GNU version, called `gawk`.

Comment: hi i dont have gawk, is there any other way. please help

Comment: @asn123, what system are you on?

Comment: SunOS Airstore 5.10 Generic_118833-17 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

Comment: Solaris nawk don't have strftime() function.