# Convert from Unix Epoch to day and time in Java

Tags: java, time, epoch

I need to convert a UNIX epoch time to day and time something like:

> e.g. 1309778593 to Monday, 11:23:12

Any help?

Comment: Check out this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with help of following code-

```
String epochTime = "1309778593";
Date convertedDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochTime) * 1000);
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

This will print-

```
Mon Jul 04 13:23:13 CEST 2011
```

I think this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Pull the date components from this:

```
new Date(1309778593)
```