# Convert epoch time to dd/MM/yyyy using JAVA

Tags: java

I need to convert a String which is a epoch (Unix time) format to a Date class an after a String formatted (dd/MM/yyyy).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far. We're not going to make your work for you as you surely understand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions about parsing and formatting dates are one of the most common type of Java questions here. Please do a seach, you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unix time is the number of seconds since 1 January 1970, so this should work

```
Date date = new Date(unixTime * 1000);
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
```

BTW SimpleDateFormat accepts millis as argument too, so it is possible to get the same result as

```
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(unixTime * 1000);
```

Comment: Do `unixTime * 1000L` to make sure to not lose data in the multiplication.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but only if OS supports leap seconds

Comment: If the `unixTime` is `int`, it will overflow if multiplied by the int 1000. If the constant 1000 is `long` it will not matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Date date = new Date(time);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    String formatted = format.format(date);
    System.out.println(formatted);
```