# How do I convert this JSON Weather-Time data (epoch time)into local time

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am a beginner in android Programming and creating an app that displays weather information of Morning (6am),afternoon(12pm) and Night(9pm) of the same day.
I am using JSON data from  this website.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=kangra,india&appid=41352ca35dd1be72cc7d9f47351d1b41&units=metric
The time stamp given in the link is in UTC and I am having trouble to display weather information according to local time.(I need weather info at 6am,12pm and 6 pm Local time)
I'd  appreciate a lot of anyone can help solve my problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant snippet of data in your post itself, rather than link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix epoch time to Java Date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the documentation of your data feed to know for sure the meaning of the data.

I am going to *guess* that the `dt` field is a number of whole seconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00` in UTC.

Example data:

> "dt":1476576000

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1476576000L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-10-16T00:00:00Z

You can adjust that into any time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( zoneKolkata );
```

> zdtKolkata.toString(): 2016-10-16T05:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

You can do so again for other time zones.

```
ZoneId zoneMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = instant.atZone( zoneMontreal );
```

> zdtMontreal.toString(): 2016-10-15T20:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

All three of these date-time objects (`instant`, `zdtKolkata`, `zdtMontreal`) are **all the very same moment**, the same single point on the timeline. The only difference is viewing the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of different regions.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The date format above is an [`epoch` format (or Unix time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To convert to java's `Date` you can do (as from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object))

```
Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
```

Being `date` the `int` or `long` value returned from the api, like `1476576000`