# Convert Unix time stamp to Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

I have Long value **1282680754000** where if I check this value in https://www.epochconverter.com/ it gives me **Tuesday, August 24, 2010 8:12:34 PM**

But if I use new **DateTime(1282680754000).toDate()** I get **Wed Aug 25 01:42:34 IST 2010** (It is adding +5.30 hour)

How to get **Tuesday, August 24, 2010 8:12:34 PM**  for **1282680754000** in java

Comment: U have to use conversion to utc

Comment: even with DateTime(timeInstance).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()); it givves same value

Comment: no it does not `System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1282680754000L)));` for example. This is just about playing with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` I guess

Comment: It's not adding 5.5 hours.  It's just displaying the same moment in time differently.

Comment: On the original of this duplicate, see specifically the modern solution using *java.time* classes in the [Answer by Przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444188/642706).

Comment: Always **search Stack Overflow** before posting. You can assume any basic question about date-time has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_282_680_754_000L)
```

or

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_282_680_754_000L).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

(using java.time, the modern Java date and time API; you may consider it the successor of Joda-Time).

The latter will give you an `OffsetDateTime`, which you can then format into youe desired format.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your code is correct. You got the correct `Date`. The only things are:

- For most purposes you shouldn’t want a `java.util.Date`. That class is long outdated and has design problems, which was the major background for development of Joda-Time and later java.time.
- Your `Date` was printed in your local time (IST, probably India Standard Time or Asia/Kolkata) where you expected UTC. A `Date` has got neither time zone nor offset in it. When you print it, its `toString` method grabs your JVM’s time zone setting and renders the time in this time zone — in your case in IST. This behaviour surprises many.

**Link:** [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s coding blog

Answer (score 0):

```
 String result = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .toFormat()
            .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1282680754000L));

 System.out.println(result); // Tuesday, August 24, 2010 8:12:34 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `toDate`, you are converting it to a `Date` object, which its `toString` method uses your operating system default time zone to print its value (you can see the IST in your question).

Just for reference examine the follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1282680754000L, DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
  System.out.println(dateTime.toDate().toGMTString());
}
```

> 24 Aug 2010 20:12:34 GMT

against (my default time zone is IDT):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1282680754000L,DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
  System.out.println(dateTime.toDate());
}
```

> Tue Aug 24 23:12:34 IDT 2010

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).